# Communication between forms in different processes

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a form1 with a textBox and the following method:

```
public void ChangeText()
{
    textBox.Text = "A";
}
```

The application runs a form of class Form1 - We'll call it mainForm.
That main form starts another process that creates another form of class Form1 - Let's call it childForm.

I now want to click a button on mainForm and have the childForm's `ChangeText()` method called so that the childForm's textBox is the one that is effected.

I've been looking for a while and I can't seem to make it work. I'm not entirely sure it's even possible.

API doesn't seem to give me the option at all and with WCF the method is being called, but the original form is not recognized.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but since the two forms are in different processes, you'll need an inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism like [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx) or [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx). Or you can use [this technique](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSendWMCOPYDATA-97e6644e).

Comment: I've been trying WCF and messaging but, as mentioned, the original form's method is called but the form itself is not efected.

Comment: Why are you creating a second process, instead of having multiple forms within the same process?  It would make communicating much easier.

Comment: What's actually happening is that the first form is creating several child forms (using form.Show()). For performance reasons, if we need additional windows, we're exploring starting additional processes. The example given above is the simplest form of what I'm trying to accomplish in the long run. Communication between the "MainForms".

Comment: @David: I used "WM_COPYDATA for IPC (CSSendWM_COPYDATA)" as you suggested and it works beautifully. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, but since the two forms are in different processes, you'll need an inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism like [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx). Or you can use [this technique](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSendWMCOPYDATA-97e6644e).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to edit logic on the way

--

If mainForm instantiates childForm then it should also hold a reference to it.

i.e. private Form childForm = new Form();

Call mainForm.ChangeText() which will look something like this (this gets called by the event so the parameters will in fact be the event and sender parameters):

```
public void ChangeText(EventArgs e, Sender sender)
{
   this.childForm.ChangeText(EventArgs e, Sender sender)
}
```

You can also access the textBox directly if you make it public

i.e.

```
this.childForm.textBox1.Text = text
```

- Corrected accessor mistake as pointed out by another user

Comment: It doesn't matter if `ChangeText` is public if `childForm` is *in another process*.

Comment: I am creating a process and not the forms, so neither the child nor the parent form have an instance of each other.
if I call this.childForm.ChangeText(EventArgs e, Sender sender) I would get a Null exception since childForm would be null.